# Calculate avg time between multiple dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Part | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/1/2021 |
| 1 | 9/8/2021 |
| 1 | 9/15/2021 |
| 2 | 9/1/2020 |
| 2 | 9/1/2021 |
| 2 | 9/1/2022 |

The dataframe is already sorted by part, then by date.

I am trying to find the `average days` between each date grouped by the `Part` column.

So the desired output would be:

| Part | Avg Days |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 365 |

How would you go about processing this data to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` "Date", use `apply`+ `diff` to get the time delta between consecutive rows, and get the `mean`:

```
(df.groupby('Part')['Date']
   .apply(lambda s: s.diff().mean())
   .to_frame()
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
Part     Date         
1      7 days
2    365 days
```

Comment: Thank you!! That provides the data I'm looking for.